# Merging overlapping lines?

Tags: qgis, merge, line

I've got one shapefile with bus lines and the sum of their passengers. Unfortunately, some lines are sharing some sections. I want to show exactly how many passengers are on theses sections, so I explode the lines to get a smaller interval. Now I want to sum the passengers on each section but I really don't know how. As I said, all the data is just in one shapefile.

I tried to merge but without any section without any success. Do you know how I can merge according to their location?

If that's not possible I tried also to make one shapefile for each bus and afterward I tried to clip it. Unfortunately, I'm also not able to clip and sum up the fields.

[image]

I just want to merge these three layers and sumarize the values from "Linie_Lo_3".